# How to wait until dynamic content is loaded into paragraph?

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This question is related to selenium webdriver I used in C#.

For a test case I want to Assert a Text which is loaded in a Form. This text is placed into a div selected by ;
 `wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("div.introduction > h2")));`

However the content in this element is dynamic loaded. Due to processing issues the JavaScript isn't done with replacing the second text in this div
'div.introduction > h2'

So I get Assert error's when I try to Assert my text in my Form. I could resolve this issue by e.g. thread.sleep, but I want use that. But I have no idea how to resolve this timming issue?

Comment: can you please post the source code before and after presence of the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before checking for the element you could do a wait-for-ajax call, something that would look like this:

```
wait.Until(d => (bool)(d as IJavaScriptExecutor).ExecuteScript("return jQuery.active == 0"));
```